# ¿Qué control usar para representar gráficos en C#? (no pictureBox)

Tags: c#, picturebox

Tengo un formulario y tengo que presentar la información en formato de velas japonesas, tal como el siguiente gráfico:

[image: Ejemplo de gráfico con velas japonesas]

Había optado por usar el control pictureBox, pero veo que el color del borde no se puede cambiar (exceptuando con un pequeño truco que he leído que consiste de meter el pictureBox dentro de un control Panel).

Necesitaría desplazar el gráfico de izquierda a derecha para ir recorriendo los valores del archivo en cuestión.

¿Qué control me recomiendan que use?
A poder ser que no sea un pictureBox.

Comment: Buscando en google y en otras preguntas de Stack Overflow encontré esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13052823/4092887) . La gráfica en inglés creo que se llama "candlestick". También puedes descargar este [control](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Forms-Samples-26bf2a53) - allí dice que soporta la gráfica que buscas crear. Si nada de esto te sirvió, te invito a buscar `japanese candlestick chart c#` y edita tu pregunta con los resultados de tu investigación. Buena suerte.